# Animate UIButton changes location on text change

Tags: ios, objective-c, layout, uibutton, uianimation

I'm having trouble changing my button text after animation.

Defined in my .h file

```
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *btnCheck;
```

I call this method when i want to animate the button location change

```
- (void)updateViews {
    if(checkedIn){
        [UIView animateWithDuration:0.3f
                          delay:0.0f
                        options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionNone
                     animations:^{
                         btnClear.hidden = YES;
                         [btnCheck setFrame:CGRectMake(90, btnCheck.frame.origin.y,        btnCheck.frame.size.width, btnCheck.frame.size.height)];
                     }
                     completion:nil];

    }else{
        [UIView animateWithDuration:0.3f
                          delay:0.0f
                        options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionNone
                     animations:^{
                         [btnCheck setFrame:CGRectMake(20, btnCheck.frame.origin.y, btnCheck.frame.size.width, btnCheck.frame.size.height)];
                     }
                     completion:^(BOOL finished){
                         btnClear.hidden = NO; 
                     }];
    }
    checkedIn = !checkedIn;
}
```

That works perfect, pics included below for reference:
[image: Animation]
[image: Animation]

The problem is as soon as i try change the name of the button it jumps back to its original frame.

I change the button text in another method like this,

> btnCheck.titleLabel.text = @"test";

And as soon as i change that the button jumps back

[image: test]

What's causing the button frame to be reset?
I've tried changing it before the animation,during and on completion. It animates to the new location and jumps back.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It was Autolayout that caused the problem. Disabled that and everything worked

Answer (score 3):

This will probabily not answer your question, but I'll show you a better way to change a frame when you want to change only one property in your frame

```
 CGRect buttonFrame = [btnCheck frame];
 buttonFrame.origin.x = newXOrigin;
 [UIView animateWithDuration:0.3f
                  animations:^{
                    [btnCheck setFrame:buttonFrame]; 
                 }];
```

I prefer this method, because you don't have to create a new CGRect and copy paste all the unmodified frame attributes. Ow and you might wanna get the hidden assignment out of the animation block, since that cannot be animated

Comment: Thanks, didn't think of that at the time. Looks so much simpler.

Answer (score 2):

You should not change `UIButton`'s title that way. Instead, try setting it's title using `setTitle:forState:` method. Try this, and let me know if this was helpful, Good Luck!

Comment: It gives the same issue, i used the following:
[btnCheck setTitle:@"test" forState:UIControlStateNormal];

Comment: Then it's really strange, I would highly recommend you to double check your code.

Comment: As per images you have provided, I don't think that your button is changing it's frame, maybe you are changing text alignment of the `titleLabel` somewhere in your code?

Comment: I've commented most other non essential code out, nothing else is changing just the frame and the text. I also added a printout of the frames in the completion of the animation. X Y Width Height
20.000000 20.000000 100.000000 58.000000
90.000000 20.000000 100.000000 58.000000
It also just happens as i change the text. after that it changes the frame to the correct location and back